# annotate font is different from the other texts in the figure with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add some annotations to the graph that I create with ggplot2 2. The font size and type seem to be different for the annotations compared to everything else. I have a font size of 20 for the labels and the legend, but even with a size of 12 and specifying the font type (family) as Arial, the annotations look very different than the rest of the graph.

```
fontsize <- 20 / .pt
plot <- ggplot(material) + theme_void() + scale_color_hue() +
 aes(x = strain, y = stress, colour = type, group = type) +
 geom_xspline(size = 1, spline_shape = 0.5) + labs(x = "Strain (in/in)", 
 y = "Stress (ksi)", color = element_blank()) + theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
   legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
   axis.title.y = element_text(size=20, colour="black", angle = 90, vjust = -22, hjust = 0.55),
   axis.title.x = element_text(size=20, colour="black", vjust = 7, hjust = 0.6),
   axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
   legend.text=element_text(size=20), legend.box.margin = margin(10,10,10,10),
   legend.spacing.x = unit(0, 'cm')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") + scale_x_continuous(trans = "reverse") + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), size = 0.3) + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), size = 0.3) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = -0.0009226, yend = 0), size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.0009226, y = 0, xend = -0.0011707, yend = -0.94), size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = -4.958, xend = -0.00333, yend = -4.958), 
           size = 0.6, linetype = "dotted", colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.00333, y = 0, xend = -0.00333, yend = -4.958), 
           size = 0.6, linetype = "dotted", colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.0024, y = 0, xend = -0.0024, yend = -4.958), 
           size = 0.6, linetype = "dotted", colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -3.75E-03, y = 0, xend = -3.75E-03, yend = -4.6011), 
           size = 0.6, linetype = "dotted", colour = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -0.0046736, y = 0, xend = -0.0046736, yend = -4.6011), 
           size = 0.6, linetype = "dotted", colour = "black") +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y= -0.94, label = "f'", size = fontsize, family = "sans")
```

The resulted graph is
[image]

How can I send all the text in the figure to the same font and size?

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the font `size` in the `theme` is usually specified in `pt` (points) while when specifying `size` inside of the `geom`s or `annotate` it is measured in `mm`. This means that the size of you `axis.title` is `20pt`, while the size of your annotation is `12mm` or approx. `34pt`. Therefore, if you want the same font sizes you have to do a conversion for which `ggplot2` offers a helper constant `.pt`.

If you want the annotation to have the same size as e.g. the `axis.title` you have to set the font`size` in `annotate` equal to `20 / .pt`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

family <- "sans"
fontsize <- 20 / .pt

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + theme_void() +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) +
  annotate("text", x = 0, y= -0.94, label = "f'", size = fontsize, family = "sans") +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(hp = 100, mpg = -.94), aes(label = "f'"), size = fontsize) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=20, colour="black", angle = 90, vjust = -22, hjust = 0.55),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=20, colour="black", vjust = 7, hjust = 0.6),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=20), legend.box.margin = margin(10,10,10,10),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0, 'cm'))
```

[image]

Comment: I just updated the fontsize as you suggested but the font is actually looking much smaller than the theme() texts. I have updated the original post to show the updated figure

Comment: Hi Maral. I know what you mean. When I look at the figure it seems as if the axis and legend texts are larger then the annotation. Nonetheless I would guess that this is truely not the case. As a check and clean comparison use e.g. `Strain (in/in)` for the annotation to the plot instead of the `f'`.